# Allow newly connecting user to disconnect existing Remote Desktop (RDP) session

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-server-2016

On Windows Server 2016 we have limited the number of sessions to 2. This works fine but if a third user connects they are locked out, until someone gives up their session. We want to allow the third user to forcibly disconnect one of the two users, in case one of those forgot to sign out.

Sessions were limited via gpedit.msc and the n"Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections".

We also set the sessions to disconnect after 3 hours idle time, so we wouldn't get locked out forever in the "forgot to sign out" scenario, but currently we could still get locked out for 3 hours if both users forget to sign out.

Is there a way for the newly connecting user to disconnect one of the existing sessions, without allowing an unlimited number of sessions? This used to be an option and it would show each session's idle time, too, but now it doesn't. The connecting user is an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I found out from serverfault that "mstsc /admin" will force a disconnect.